# Linq-to-XML: Adding enumerations to objects

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to figure out how to add an enumeration to an object with Linq. For example:

```
Dim thingBlock = <Things>
                      <Thing Name="Ish">
                          <SmallThing>Jibber</SmallThing>
                          <SmallThing>Jabber</SmallThing>
                      </Thing>
                      <Thing Name="Ugly Guy">
                         <SmallThing Name="Carl"></SmallThing>
                         <SmallThing Marks="Marks"></SmallThing>
                      </Thing>
                  </Things>
Dim myList As New List(Of Thing)
myList.AddRange(thingBlock.<Thing>.Select(Function(th) New Thing With {.Name = th.@Name}))

Public Class Thing
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property SmallThings As New List(Of String)
End Class
```

This works well to create new `Thing` and add them to `myList`, but I can't figure out how to add the IEnumerable of String to my `SmallThings` list. For example, this *doesn't* work:

```
myList.AddRange(thingBlock.<Thing>.Select(Function(th) New Thing With {.Name = th.@Name, th.Select(Function(st) .SmallThings.Add(st.Elements.@Name.ToString)}))
```

I just want to add all the `<SmallThing>.@Name` to `SmallThings` property of the `Thing` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure which values you wanted to extract from the `<SmallThing>`s but this seems to work.

```
' adds "Jibber" and "Jabber" '
myList.AddRange(thingBlock.<Thing>.Select(Function(th) New Thing With         _
    {                                                                         _
        .Name = th.@Name,                                                     _
        .SmallThings = th...<SmallThing>.Select(Function(st) st.Value).ToList _
    }))

' adds "Carl" '
myList.AddRange(thingBlock.<Thing>.Select(Function(th) New Thing With         _
    {                                                                         _
        .Name = th.@Name,                                                     _
        .SmallThings = th...<SmallThing>.Select(Function(st) st.@Name).ToList _
    }))
```

The key was to convert the projection to a list since `SmallThings` expected a list (`Select` returns an `IEnumerable(Of T)`)